# How to get most recent tweet of followers?

Tags: php, rest, twitter, tweets

I am trying to get the most recent tweet of each follower.
First I got the ids of all the followers using:

```
$usids = $tweet->get('followers/ids', array('screen_name' => 'kfcarabia'));
```

Now, how can I get the most recent tweet per follower?